# Storing date as text in database but need to find records between two dates?

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I am storing dates as VARCHAR in mysql tables. I actually have a invoice table that stores invoice details along with its date. I store those dates with this function of php in VARCHAR column.

```
date("d/m/y")
```

Now i need to generate reports of sales like from 4/5/2012 to 4/5/2013. I am confused as to how to find the date range. Please guide.

I am using codeigniter.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this question for storing dates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427746/codeigniter-date-format?rq=1

Comment: Do you have any specific reason for storing dates as varchar. Storing as integer at least makes more sense than varchar. Could you possibly rework your database? Store dates as dates yyyy-mm-dd. If you want the above format, you could `list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $date)` and reorder for display as `echo $day."/".$month."/".$year`. Just suggesting, see my reply below.

Answer (score 1):

If it's dates why not store as date? You could now add another column, then with a script or program populate this new column with the parsed and recomposed dates. Thus, your future queries can work with a date data type.

Comment: now how do i go with that? storing date("d/m/y") in mysql datatype and then retrieval. Please guide.

Comment: To do the initial conversion, you could read all existing dates (stored already in d/m/y), convert them and store back in the new column. At best, you now delete the old varchar column and only use the new one.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can get the date from char to  timestamp , of course, you need to do some format for your date...

here is some sample...

```
$senttime = strtotime($date . ' ' . $hour . ':' . $min . ':00');
$exdate   = strtotime($exdate . ' 00:00:00');
$now      = strtotime("now");

if ($now < $senttime && $senttime < $exdate) {...
```

than you can get the range...

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL's built in string to date parsing

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date_column`,'%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2012-04-05' to '2013-04-05'
```

or in CI ActiveRecord

```
$this->db->select('*')
$this->db->from('your_table');
$this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(`date_column`,"%d/%m/%Y") >=', '2012-04-05');
$this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(`date_column`,"%d/%m/%Y") <=', '2013-04-05');
$query = $this->db->get();
$results = $query->result();
```

Comment: this doesn't work $this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(`date`,"%d/%m/%y") >=', '26/02/13');
  $this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(`date`,"%d/%m/%y") <=', '26/02/13');

Comment: date should be a mysql reserved word. It should be used for your column name. Like @Wing showed above, use the date column name before the format and not the word date.

Comment: I changed the column name to: invoiceDate and then fired this: 
$this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE("invoiceDate","%d/%m/%y")', '26/02/13',FALSE); DOESN'T WORK

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing a suggestion here rather than an explicit answer.

Do you have any specific reason for storing dates as varchar. Storing as integer at least makes more sense than varchar. Could you possibly rework your database? Store dates as dates yyyy-mm-dd. Or is that completely impossible at this time?

If you wanted the above format as display, you could

```
<?php list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $date) ?>
```

and reorder for display as

```
<?php echo $day."/".$month."/".$year ?>
```

If it is completely impossible to rework the db, then use MYSQL STR_TO_DATE

Please see if this link could be of help: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php

[EDIT]

```
<?php
$date_from = '26/02/13';
$date_to = '26/02/13';

//Because STR_TO_DATE would create a valid date from what you have in varchar.
list($day, $month, $year) = explode("/", $date_from);
$date_from = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day;
list($day, $month, $year) = explode("/", $date_to);
$date_to = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day;

$this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(`date`,"%d/%m/%y") >=', $date_from);
$this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(`date`,"%d/%m/%y") <=', $date_to);
$query = $this->db->get('TABLENAME');

//use your result here
?>
```

Comment: what are the disadvantages of using MYSQL STR_TO_DATE?

Comment: It certainly won't be as fast as using date straight. Outside that, none that I can think of. Just make sure your format is correct. And since it's mysql that's doing the formatting, you probably won't notice much of the speed difference unless you are using a very large table.

Comment: i tried this to fetch all records with date 26/02/2013 with -  $this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(date,"%d/%m/%y") >=', '26/02/13'); $this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(date,"%d/%m/%y") <=', '26/02/13'); DOESN'T WORK

Comment: Like I said, you cannot use date as column name. It is reserved for mysql. Change the word date to a valid column name for the date field. If your column is named date, I suggest your change it to something that would work. STR_TO_DATE(use_column_name_here,"%d/%m/%y") or at least quote the word `date` and see if that works

Comment: Please my recent edit. if date is your column name, you might want to use back tick to quote it. First prepare what you send to mysql for comparison. Since you are converting the date data to a valid mysql date, compare the result with a valid mysql date.